# Streaming Desktop

Tags: video-streaming

I am looking for a clean way to stream a desktop's video to more than one computer across a few building. I am looking to a solution to this locking up or a rebuild of my process. I am open to look into any solution.

Let me give a little history. I am in charge of metrics and metric tv displays. I use Graphite/Grafana/Dashing for software to save and display data. Also use some custom software to get data mined. I use full screen chrome with a tab rotator to display all the dashboards. This is very hard on the server also my time to make sure all tabs are displayed correct. So I set up a system using VLC to capture the desktop and display it across the network to other TVs. The Tvs use windows comps to pick up the stream and display it using a basic html wrapped VLC plugin site. The Stream I am using is Http at 10fps. The problem I am having is after a "random" amount of time the Client sides site will lock up and need to refreshed.

```
<html>
<head><title>Company</title></head>
<body style="background:#000000">

<embed 
type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" 
version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" 
width="100%" 
height="100%" 
id="vlc" 
loop="yes" 
autoplay="yes" 
target="http://10.10.10.20:8080/">

</embed>
</body>
</html>
```

I would love to also add in some pause and rewind function.

I can not use something like Livestream, youtube, veetle, Ustream or any of the others due to regulations the data can not go off the local network.

I am working my way towards setting up raspberry pi for the TV's clients. I would like to control the clients using fabric. I am going to try and automate the on/off of the tvs using hdmi cec.

So the core of my questions are if anyone knows of a way to fix this freezing or of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching from HTTP to a stateless streaming protocol such as MPEG-TS over UDP - my experience with VLC shows that streaming over this protocol is able to survive even severe network disruptions and will resume automatically.

This, of course, becomes a question of whether your recording software is capable of outputting MPEG-TS over UDP. I do not have familiarity with screen capture software so I cannot assist on that point.

Comment: Are you talking about RTP /  MPEG Trandport Stream in VLC? I am using VLC for the capture software right now. Do you recommend any other software? I would love something I can start via command line on either windows or ubuntu.

Comment: I am not familiar with using VLC as a streaming server but "RTP / MPEG Transport Stream" sound like the right thing, yes. You'll want to set the VLC server to send the data to a broadcast address like 244.1.2.3 and a random port e.g. 1234 and then make the VLC cliens listen on the same broadcast address (udp://244.1.2.3:1234). FFmpeg can certainly stream from a command line but I am not sure if it can capture the screen for you. Probably VLC can also be used from the command line, though I have not tried it.

Comment: I will try this out today and get back to you.

Comment: I still not note get the RTP/MPEG to work. I Tried changing the port number on the html file but it just sits there blank.